# calculating angle between two points on edge of circle Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, geometry, angle, degrees

How would you calculate the degrees between two points on the edge of a circle in Swift.

[image]

Comment: Do you know for sure this is a circle? Like, you know the center of the circle? Because two points does not a circle make, since an infinite number of different circles can be desecribed by two points - you need a third, either on the circle or the origin.

Comment: i know the origin also @corsiKa

Comment: So then you can just use arctan(delta y/delta x). I don't know what swift sprite key is, so I would not be sure of the format for the code for that.

Edit: most programming languages using trig uses radians, so your output might be in radians. If there's a function to convert it to degrees, just use that; otherwise, use the formula to convert it to degrees which is rads*180/pi

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Given points `p1`, `p2` on a circle with center `center`,
you would compute the difference vectors first:

```
let v1 = CGVector(dx: p1.x - center.x, dy: p1.y - center.y)
let v2 = CGVector(dx: p2.x - center.x, dy: p2.y - center.y)
```

Then

```
let angle = atan2(v2.dy, v2.dx) - atan2(v1.dy, v1.dx)
```

is the (directed) angle between those vectors in radians, and

```
var deg = angle * CGFloat(180.0 / M_PI)
```

the angle in degrees. The computed value can be in the range -360 .. 360, so you
might want to normalize it to the range 0 <= deg < 360 with

```
if deg < 0 { deg += 360.0 }
```

Comment: will this code work on an iPad? all that is going to happen is that the circle will enlarge a little bit.

Comment: @PoKoBros: This is just math, it works on any device. It only computes an angle, so what do you mean by "the circle will enlarge a bit" ?

Comment: I just mean the radius of the circle will double ok an iPad

Comment: @PoKoBros: Sorry, I don't get it. This question was about computing an angle from three points (center, p1, p2). The radius is not even involved in the formula. So how/where does the *"radius double on an iPad"*?

Comment: For some reason when I try the same exact code on the iPad, it does not work.

Comment: @PoKoBros: Can you provide a concrete example of input values, actual output and expected output?

Comment: I actually only needed to calculate up to radians not degrees so I stopped at the let angle line in your answer. I guess what I am trying to ask is that shouldn't the radians outputted be the same in all circles?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71433/discussion-between-pokobros-and-martin-r).